# Does a proper class have arbitrary large subsets?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Assume that we are working in ZFC, that we have a well-formed formula $P(x)$, that $x$ is the only free variable of $P(x)$, that there is *no* set $S$ such that 
$$
\forall x\ (x\in S\iff P(x)),
$$ 
and that $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

Is there necessarily a set $T$ of cardinality $\alpha$ such that 
$$
\forall x\ (x\in T\implies P(x))\ ?
$$

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question. If $S$ is the proper class of all singleton sets, it obviously contains no sets of cardinality greater than 1. But the body of your question asks whether there's a set of $\alpha$ singletons, which of course is true. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @user4894 - I'd say that the class of all singletons contains the set $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$. But in case of doubt please feel free to ignore the title.

Comment: How can the class of all singletons contain a 2-element set? I'm really mystified now.

Comment: @user4894 - **If** there were a set $S$ of all singletons, we'd have $\{0\}\in S$ (in words: $\{0\}$ is a member of $S$) and $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}\subset S$ (in words: $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ is contained in, or is a subset of, $S$).

Comment: @user4894 you seem to be using "contains" in the sense of $\in$, whereas the OP is using it in the sense of $\subseteq$ (and the title makes it clear that this is in fact what they want).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I figured that out after OP's last reply. The title has been edited for clarity since I raised my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Let $P_\alpha=\{x\in V_\alpha\mid P(x)\}$. Namely, we intersect the class given by $P$ with each $V_\alpha$. So we get that $P(x)\iff\exists\alpha. x\in P_\alpha$.

Define by recursion a function $F(0)=0$, and $F(\alpha+1)=\beta$ if and only if $P_\beta$ is the first time where $P_{F(\alpha)}\subsetneq P_\beta$. Namely, the first time we add new members. For limit steps, take limits.

Now it follows that if $\kappa$ is any cardinal, then $P_{F(\kappa)}$ must have at least $\kappa$ elements. For any $\kappa$. So given any cardinal $\lambda$, we can carve out some subset of $P_{F(\lambda)}$ with the right cardinality.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to understand your answer. (I have no doubt that it is correct.) A probably silly question: do you really mean $P_{F(\alpha)}\subsetneq P_\beta$, not $P_\beta\subsetneq P_{F(\alpha)}$?

Comment: Yes. You want that $F(\alpha+1)$ will be the next time you've added new elements.

Comment: Is it not possible to have $P_0=\varnothing$? (Sorry to bother you again with this.)

Comment: Yes? So what? You said that $P$ defines a proper class. At some point, it will not be empty no more.

Comment: Assume $P_0=\varnothing$. Then $F(1)=\beta$ if and only if $P_\beta$ is the first time where $\varnothing=P_0=P_{F(0)}\subsetneq P_\beta$. But $\varnothing\subseteq P_\beta$ for all $\beta$. No?

Comment: You do notice the "not equal" part, right?

Comment: Sorry, I read "not contained" instead of "strictly contained". Thanks for your patience!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is true.

Assume to the contrary that there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that no set equinumerous to $\alpha$ is contained in $P$. Then there is a smallest such $\alpha$. However this means that for each $\beta<\alpha$ we can choose an $A_\beta$ such that $A_\beta \subseteq P$ and $|A_\beta|=|\beta|$ (employing [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick) to cut the space of candidate $A_\beta$s down to set size before choosing frely). But then $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} A_\beta \subseteq P$ and its cardinality is at least $\alpha$.

Comment: Assuming ZFC, choice is true. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Indeed. I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

In Godel-Bernays + Proper class choice, I would say *yes*.

In fact, consider your proper class $A$. Since it is not empty, there is an element inside, call it $x_0$. Now consider the proper class of elements that are not $x_0$, call it $x_0^{\bot}$ and intersect it with $A$. This cannot be $A$, so there is another element in $A$ which is not $x_0$, call it $x_1$. By induction I get an injection of ordinals into $A$.

I do believe that this proof can be reformulated in ZFC + Universal choice, but I do not feel comfortable in doing it.

Comment: This seems to assume universal choice, right?

Comment: Global choice is not needed.

Comment: Oh, feel free to edit my answer, or to post a better one, @AsafKaragila!